# Ajax : POST-method not allowed 405

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, post

I am experimenting with POST-requests in node.js and html.

Every time I am trying to post something, i get the error "POST http://IP:PORT/request 405 (Method Not Allowed)".

This happens no matter what application i am trying to do the POST-method from. I am developing in VScode and running a live-server.

I followed this tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-send-data-from-client-side-to-node-js-server-using-ajax-without-page-reloading/

Comment: Your code is actually attempting to make a Cross-domain (CORS) request, not an ordinary POST.Modern browsers will only allow Ajax calls to services in the same domain as the HTML page.

Example: A page in http://www.example.com/myPage.html can only directly request services that are in http://www.example.com, like http://www.example.com/testservice/etc. If the service is in other domain, the browser won't make the direct call (as you'd expect). Instead, it will try to make a CORS request.

Comment: Thank you. I've been looking into CORS the past hour and i am still quite confused. How can this situation be possible? The Access-control-allow-origin header contains my address but still, i cannot perform the post-method... [link] (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PgFdKdnXv2Xgmv-WiDGNG5fi_j6wxTPC/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: give access to your code else add your code here